# Impromptu - Simple pass variable to URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, impromptu

Really could use some help / logic.

I want to pass an elementid on the href of a jquery impromptu that can then be used to append to a destination url.

That is; start with a href:

```
<a class="link" href="javascript:;" elementid="66">Remove item</a>
```

I want it so that if I click on this link it will send me to: remove-element.php?elementid=66

My javascript looks like:

```
<script>
function removeItem(id) { 
var txt = 'Are you sure you want to remove this item?';
$.prompt(txt, { 
buttons: {Yes: true, Cancel: false}, 
callback: function(accept) {
if (accept) {
window.location = "remove-element.php?elementid=x";
}
return false;
}
});
}

$('a.link').click(function() {
removeItem($(this).data('id'));
return false;
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to use `$(this).data('id')`, you need to set your anchor tag as:

```
<a class="link" href="javascript:;" data-elementid="66">Remove item</a>
```

and pass in the value, as:

```
$('a.link').click(function() {
    removeItem($(this).data('id'));
    return false;
});

function removeItem(id) { 
    var txt = 'Are you sure you want to remove this item?';
    $.prompt(txt, { 
        buttons: {Yes: true, Cancel: false}, 
        callback: function(accept) {
            if (accept) {
                window.location.href = "http://your_site.com/remove-element.php?elementid=" + id;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you a tonne. Really appreciate the help. Cheers. Paul